# Node.js mongodb with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongojs

I am making a little game in node.js and as database I am using mongodb with mongojs. Currently this is the way I am handling the database conenction:

```
var mongojs = USE_DB ? require("mongojs") : null;
var db = USE_DB ? mongojs('localhost:27017/dbName', ['players','pets']) : null;
```

And for example If I want to check if username is taken upon registration, I do:

```
Database.usernameCheck= function(name,callback){
    db.account.findOne({username:name.username},function(err,result){
        if(result) callback(true);
        else callback(false);
    });
}
```

And then I call the function when a new player is registered:

```
    Database.usernameCheck(data,function(result){
        if(result){
            //username taken        
        } else {
            //add the user
        }
    });
```

I am not too much experienced with the node.js and javascript programming, but I read that the best way to do is with promises, so I would like to convert my current code to use promises instead of callbacks. Tried a couple of ways, but I failed so I decided to ask here, well, thank you for your time.

Comment: Have a look at [this rather complete post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321), this should help you understand the concepts and the existing implementations. And give you enough insight to get to it! ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I was actually hoping for example of accomplish the same concept using ex: mongoist or anything similar.

Comment: MongoJS team declares that this library has no support for promises, so you are stuck with callbacks for the mongoDB commands [clickhere](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs/issues/324)

Comment: I personally recommend Mongoose, it has a very similar approach and supports promises

Comment: @GabrielLopez that's why I said "example using ex: mongoist". I know that mongojs doesn't support promises. Can you please give me example using my code transformed for mongoose with promises? Thank you.

Comment: Got it to work switching to mongoose. Everything is better now. Thank you @GabrielLopez for the recommendation.